# Help with a malware issue

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, malware

Today I've downloaded a software called Virtual WIFI Router - it was full of malware and viruses.

Somehow I've managed to manually delete the files but it's done quite some damage.
The biggest problem is that except from Internet explorer no other software (Firefox, yahoo messeger, Bittorrent etc.) can't access the internet. I can't download anything.
I don't use any proxy or firewall.

The situation is desperate. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question isn't on-topic here. You'll probably find better help on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). Online reviews show that the software you mentioned is full of adware/crapware, but there's no mention of actual viruses. My immediate suggestion is to boot your PC in safe mode (Hold down F8 during boot on most machines). Download and install an antivirus software, and perform a full system scan. You could also try running System Restore to a point before you installed it. Good luck!

Comment: thank you Timmy but seeing as how my situation is quite desperate, this is the only section I could find...

Comment: I understand, but your question in its current form will most likely get closed or migrated to conform with the structure of the StackExchange network. It might be possible to reword it as "Which kind of software would help me clean this mess?" instead of "What do I do?" to make it more relevant. But first give System Restore a try, then we could worry about the format of the question (Control panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> System Protection -> System Restore)

Comment: i don't have that option - never did any backup, i just need to find out what is blocking my access to the internet.

Comment: Restore points are automatically created before system updates, so you might still find some unless you have explicitly turned them off. You could also try rebooting in Safe Mode and manually uninstalling all the software that have today's date, then downloading a free antivirus and running a system scan. I hope that helps, but once more, you're looking in the the wrong website

Comment: yeah, it says that no restoer points have been created on my computer... i have no idea what else to try or where to look for them...

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that I'm answering on an off-topic question, but I would like to help immediately since it's serious and he needs help. (if you want me to delete it, **please** post a comment!)

I have searched [for a way](https://serverfault.com/questions/301128/how-to-download-of-files-through-http-command-line) to download files without a browser, and I hope it will work for you. Open up your Powershell and use this code:

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("htts://www.testadress.test","file.exe")
```

Better paste the code in a notepad window before and edit the address to a real one pointing to a file. Note, the file is going to be always called file.exe if you don't change it.

Some reliable programs to remove unwanted files and viruses are below. Hopefully you are able to check the download links by yourself, because it seems to be hard to find static links quickly.

- [Adwcleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/) - it's a portable application
- [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/) - it needs an installation, it's well-known

There is a collection full of interesting software tools called GeGeek Tech Toolkit. It contains tools which are very useful for cases like these, but the most recent versions became paid donationware. Here is one source for an older version, sorry that it's not English: http://www.chip.de/downloads/GEGeek-Toolkit_71776498.html - For a translation, copy and paste the URL in the form here: https://translate.google.com

In this collection there is a folder called "Repair Tools" with many programs and fixes. Hopefully one of it with help you to fix your nasty internet issue.

Last, try a scan for corrupted Windows files. Open a command prompt with admin rights (cmd.exe), and type this: sfc /scannow

I wish you good luck!

Comment: Really a good answer,even-though this is off-topic I don't think this answer should be deleted :)its mainly about helping each other that's what we all do here ! :)